# POST request failing when using Linux path in Java

Tags: java, angular, linux, uri

I have the following @Service class in my Spring application:

```
@Service
public class FileService {
    
    //@Autowired
    //CustomerDetailsRepository customerDetailsRepository;

    //private static final String FILE_DIRECTORY = "D:\\temp\\xmlFromAdmin";
    private static final String FILE_DIRECTORY = "//opt//xmlFromAdmin";
    static String fileName = "";
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerDetailsRepository customerDetailsRepository;
    
    //private static CustomerDetails customerDetails;
    
    //private static final String TRANSFORMED_FILE_DIRECTORY = "D:\\temp\\valuesToFrontend";
    private static final String TRANSFORMED_FILE_DIRECTORY = "//opt//valuesToFrontend";
     
    public void storeFile(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        
        Path filePath = Paths.get(FILE_DIRECTORY + "/" + fileName);
        File fullFilePath = new File(FILE_DIRECTORY + "/" + fileName);
        
        String transformedFileName = TRANSFORMED_FILE_DIRECTORY+"/"+fileName;
 
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
        FileDecryption fileDecryption = new FileDecryption();
        fileDecryption.transformDocument(fullFilePath,transformedFileName);
```

From the front-end, I am taking an XML file from the user, transforming it, and feeding values to the front-end. This code is running fine when I run this on my local Windows machine, with the commented out path. However, when I put the code into Linux, file upload is failing. The path in Linux is also specified. I am getting Error 500 when uploading, even though the URL is correct. What is the error here? This is the POST request in the service file in angular:

```
uploadLicenseFile(fileName: string, file: File): Observable<any> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
      //'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization'
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,content-type=multipart/*'
    })

    let options = {headers:headers, observer: 'response'};

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('fileName', fileName);
    formData.append('file', file);

    //return this.http.post(this.url+'/fileUpload/upload', formData,options)
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.url+'/fileUpload/upload', formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

Comment: Question: why are you sending those `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers in your POST request from Angular?

Comment: I was just getting some CORS errors. I don't know if its needed or not, but on Windows it is working fine.

Comment: I see. You don't need to send them. Those come from the server side when CORS is enabled there. The POST *should* work without them.

Comment: The problem is, if its working on Windows, why error on Linux. I am using tomcat and war file. Is it because maybe the filepath is not given properly?

Comment: For the issue you actually posted about, I have no idea. You will need to debug the server side code to see what is going on. Or, if there are any logs on the server, check those for more information.

Comment: check if you have access to `rw` permission on `/opt` path

Comment: @silentsudo    how to check that? If I am using any other path too, I get this error. The frontend is in form of ROOT/ folder in /usr/local/apache/webapps folder and its owner is Root. The war file, backend code is in same direcrory, but its owner is tomcat.

Comment: “I am getting Error 500 when uploading” — That means an exception occurred in the server code.  Look in your server log, and copy and paste the entire exception stack trace, including any and all “Caused by” sections, into your question.  We have a substantially better chance of solving your problem if we know what is actually going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was permission. The files being uploaded were by tomcat user whereas the directories I created were by root. Bypassed directory creation as of now.